# Call a function once page load after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a scenario where I need a function like `xyz()` to be called once a button on page is clicked and page is loaded using javascript/jquery.
I can't call `xyz()` directly on `<Body onload="xyz()">` or inside `document.ready()` or  `$(window).on('load', function ())`.
I need the function to be called once a button is clicked and page has loaded completely. 
Below is working code on page load but not my requirement

```
<body onload="xyz();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">            
        <div id="vizContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 700px;">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Now below is my required code on button click and it is not working

```
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="functiongetdata()" />       
            <div id="vizContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 700px;">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function functiongetdata() {
            xyz();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `$(function() { $("#myButton").click(xyz); });` https://api.jquery.com/click/ . It's really not hard to google this kind of basic stuff.

Comment: you should tag javascript and jquery, this is nothing to do with c#

Comment: I think I did not explained my question properly. Actually I have public tableau report and I want to open on button click using function xyz(). But it did not showing it. But on body load it works properly.

Comment: @ShwetaGupta can you post you body load function?

Comment: @MJK I added my code. And I think akshay phadke 's suggestion will solve my problem.

Comment: probably your asp button is posting back at the same time, so the client-side code never has time to complete before the page is reloaded from scratch. Just use a normal HTML button if you don't want it to refresh the page. And `functiongetdata` is redundant. You could just do `<button type="button" onclick="xyz()">Button</button>` directly

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this

```
$(function() {
        $('button.start').click(function() {
            $('img.lazy').lazy({
                bind: "event"
            });
        });

        $('button.loadAll').click(function() {
            $('.lazy').lazy({
                bind: "event",
                delay: 0
            });
        });
    });
```

Refer this link for clear example 
http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_load-elements-by-events

Answer (score -1):

**Approach 1:**

On window load function, update a hidden field or add a flag variable and set true

```
 var myWindowIsLoaded = false
 $(window).on('load', function (){
    myWindowIsLoaded = true;
 });
```

And then on the button click check the value

```
function xyz(){
 if(myWindowIsLoaded){
   // Do your stuff
 }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Add the function in the button click event on window load

```
$(window).on('load', function (){
  $("#myButton").click(xyz); 
});
```